# Introduce your self, is the `could` usage appropriate?

Tags: american-english

I was reading the following introduce yourself text while the usage of could cought my attention:

> My name is John. I'm from Russia. My family lives there, in a small city in the south, almost in the border with China.
>   I lived part of my life there and part in italy.
>   And I came to China this year to study in Peking University, where I'm doing Master in Engineering.
>   Here in China I still didn't traveled so much but I visited some famous places in Beijing.
>   I was in the Great Wall, in the Temple of Heaven and also visited Forbiden City.
>   I'm learning Chinese here and it will be great if I **could** teach English also.

In the last phrase, shouldn't be better to use "can" instead of "could"?

Comment: It's a **subjunctive** tense, which with very few exceptions employs the same inflections as past tense. So it should be **could** and not **can**. There are, however, a few other flaws in the grammar of the text.

Comment: @Igid *quite* a few ;-)

Comment: "My family lives there, in a small city in the south, almost **on** the border with China. I lived part of my life there and part in Italy. And I came to China this year to study **at** Peking University, where I'm doing **a** Master**s** in Engineering. Here in China I still **haven't** traveled so much but I **have** visited some famous places in Beijing. I **visited/went to** the Great Wall, the Temple of Heaven and also **the** Forbidden City. I'm learning Chinese here and it **would** be great if I could teach English also."

Comment: @Igid That's a lot of free editing.

Comment: @Lambie I bill by the minute, but the first one's free.

Comment: @igid Ha ha, good one. I just got a third hat! :)

Comment: Surprised we haven't done this yet.  The ELU people have:  [When do I use can or could](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1/when-do-i-use-can-or-could)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - "could" is appropriate.

However, "it will" should be "it would."  "If would be great if I could teach English also."